# How to Dynamically Change Chromatic Parameters in Storybook Using a Custom Decorator?

Tags: reactjs, chromium, storybook

I'm working with Storybook (version 7.0.7) for a React project and trying to integrate Chromatic for visual testing. My goal is to dynamically adjust Chromatic parameters based on a configuration file, controlling which components get snapshot testing and their specific viewports.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Created a custom decorator in .storybook/preview.js to read component-specific settings from a JSON configuration file and apply these settings to Chromatic parameters.
2. Used environment variables to determine whether Chromatic snapshots should be captured for specific components and their modes (e.g., desktop, mobile).

However, I'm facing issues where the Chromatic parameters set in the custom decorator are not being applied. Here's a snippet of my current implementation:

```
// .storybook/preview.js
export const decorators = [
    (Story, context) => {
        const componentName = context.kind.split('/').pop();
        // Logic to parse and apply settings from the config file
        context.parameters = {
            ...context.parameters,
            ...parseEnvConfig(componentName)
        };
        return <Story />;
    }
];
```